# rails: using the jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ plugin.

In my gemfile, I have (and I made sure the gem is installed):

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I downloaded jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js into the app/assets/javascripts directory

I added the CSS section to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.erb

I added the following to app/assets/javascript/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon

$(
  function() {
    $('.date_with_hours_and_minutes').datetimepicker(
      {dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd hh:mm'}   )
  }
);
```

In my view, I have:

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date_time, id: "date_with_hours_and_minutes" %>
```

I am not getting any errors, but I am not seeing the datetime picker either. Any ideas?

Comment: are the two periods in `$('.date_with_hours_and_minutes')..datetimepicker` a typo in your question or in your code?

Comment: Typo in in the question. I was fixing it while you were writing your comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('#date_with_hours_and_minutes').datetimepicker(
```

you need to attack the id

**Update**

In addition to the above, I notice you are trying to use dateFormat to handle time, and I wonder if it's necessary to timeFormat instead:

```
$('#date_with_hours_and_minutes').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd',
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
});
```

Comment: Some progress. I am seeing the calendar now, but I am not seeing the time picker.

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything other than the date picker

Answer (score 1):

either use one of below

change attach event to `id: date_with_hours_and_minutes` instead of class as you have defined id on the field

```
 $('.date_with_hours_and_minutes').datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  })
```

to

```
$('#date_with_hours_and_minutes').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
})
```

or if you have many datetimepickers on the view

attach class to them

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date_time, class: "date_with_hours_and_minutes" %>


$('.date_with_hours_and_minutes').datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd '
});
```

Comment: I fixed the class vs id thing, but I am still only seeing the date picker. No sign of the time picker.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper, did it get fixed?

Comment: Adding the # and keeping the id fixes it, but I am still seeing only the date picker (calendar widget), but not the time picker.